# Assign index number after every two consecutive row within a group after pandas groupby

Tags: python

I have a dataframe like below:

```
 TileDesc       ReportDesc     UrlLink     
   'AA'       'New Report-1'   'link-1'
   'AA'       'New Report-2'   'link-2'
   'AA'       'New Report-1'   'link-1'
   'AA'       'New Report-1'   'link-1'
   'AA'       'New Report-1'   'link-1'
   'BB'       'New Report-4'   'link-4'
   'BB'       'New Report-2'   'link-2'
   'BB'       'New Report-4'   'link-4'
   'BB'       'New Report-6'   'link-6'
```

Now I want to add a column to this that will maintain a sequence of integer which would change after every 2 consecutive times. So the resultant dataframe would look like:

```
 TileDesc       ReportDesc     UrlLink    Group     
   'AA'       'New Report-1'   'link-1'     1
   'AA'       'New Report-2'   'link-2'     1
   'AA'       'New Report-1'   'link-1'     2
   'AA'       'New Report-4'   'link-4'     2
   'AA'       'New Report-6'   'link-1'     3
   'BB'       'New Report-4'   'link-4'     1
   'BB'       'New Report-2'   'link-2'     1
   'BB'       'New Report-4'   'link-4'     2
   'BB'       'New Report-6'   'link-6'     2
```

I am following the `ngroup()` approach but not able to get through.

```
df['Group'] = df.groupby(['TileDesc']).ngroup()
```

The above code snippet is giving me same Group Number for each Group. I.e. for `AA` for all three I am getting 0, and then for all `BB` I am getting 1 and so on.

My second approach was more like:

```
df['Index'] = df.index + 1
df['Group'] = df['Index'].apply(lambda x : math.ceil(x/4))
```

But this doesn't consider `TileDesc`

What I am missing here?

**Edit**
The group value ONLY changes after each two consecutive row within a TileDesc group.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could group by and use `cumcount()`. The added trick is that you can replace the initial 0 ( `cumcount` starts from 0) with blank and replace with 1 (i.e. `bfill`):

```
df['Group'] =  df.groupby('TileDesc').cumcount().replace(0,np.nan).bfill().astype(int)
```

result:

```
   TileDesc      ReportDesc   UrlLink  Group
0      'AA'  'New Report-1'  'link-1'      1
1      'AA'  'New Report-2'  'link-2'      1
2      'AA'  'New Report-1'  'link-1'      2
3      'BB'  'New Report-4'  'link-4'      1
4      'BB'  'New Report-2'  'link-2'      1
5      'BB'  'New Report-4'  'link-4'      2
6      'CC'  'New Report-4'  'link-4'      1
7      'CC'  'New Report-2'  'link-2'      1
8      'CC'  'New Report-4'  'link-4'      2
9      'CC'  'New Report-4'  'link-4'      3
10     'CC'  'New Report-2'  'link-2'      4
11     'CC'  'New Report-4'  'link-4'      5
```

Added an extra 'CC' section to demonstrate.

Comment: But you see in `CC`, after 2 rows the Group value is increasing. Let me reframe the OP. Ideally as per the OP, it Group Value should only increase after every two consecutive rows by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use cumsum, but `//2 +1` to increment only every second line

(sorry, my copy-paste came out a bit broken, but it works)

```py
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
  TileDesc ReportDesc   UrlLink
0     'AA'  Report-1'  'link-1'
1     'AA'  Report-2'  'link-2'
2     'AA'  Report-1'  'link-1'
3     'AA'  Report-1'  'link-1'
4     'AA'  Report-1'  'link-1'
5     'BB'  Report-4'  'link-4'
6     'BB'  Report-2'  'link-2'
7     'BB'  Report-4'  'link-4'
8     'BB'  Report-6'  'link-6'

In [39]: df['Group'] = df.groupby('TileDesc').cumcount() // 2 + 1

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
  TileDesc ReportDesc   UrlLink  Group
0     'AA'  Report-1'  'link-1'      1
1     'AA'  Report-2'  'link-2'      1
2     'AA'  Report-1'  'link-1'      2
3     'AA'  Report-1'  'link-1'      2
4     'AA'  Report-1'  'link-1'      3
5     'BB'  Report-4'  'link-4'      1
6     'BB'  Report-2'  'link-2'      1
7     'BB'  Report-4'  'link-4'      2
8     'BB'  Report-6'  'link-6'      2
```